# Looking for a natural language match with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex, match-against

I am using **match() against()** to match up different values across tables which are similar, however it is unable to match the following two values:

`WERE HERE BECAUSE WERE LARGE` and `ANATHEMA were here because TS M`

Even though it **is** able to match the following:

`ANTHOLOGY 3` and `BEATLES anthology 3 ALBUM COVER BADGE`

But you can see that they are very similar, is there a way for match()against() to realise how similar they are? Since in terms of the the letters they contain these two values are more similar to each other than any other possible value it could match them against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to MySql [Full-Text Stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) **were** is the stopword

you need to just add this to your **.cnf file**, restart mysql engine and rebuild indexes:

```
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: this is the path of mysql installed directory /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
Welcome, im glad if this work

Answer (score 0):

I believe the words you are looking for are [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). For this reason they are unable to match.

Comment: Thanks, is it alright to edit the storage/myisam/ft_static.c file and remove 'were' or is there some PHP code I can put in my file to achieve this?